# Missing emails from a scheduled report

Tags: ssrs

I have a scheduled report with a query used to determine the recipients. Every time the report runs, there seems to be a few people who are not receiving the emails.
I enabled SMTP logging, and indeed the missing people are not in the logs at all.
What steps can I do to further debug this issue?

Comment: Is there any pattern to this? Are the recipients internal/external to your network? Ive had problems with apps sending emails ok to internal domain accts but exchange wouldnt allow emails to be sent to external recipients.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a pattern. Somebody that got an email yesterday, might not get one today....